# Sorting elements based on multiple conditions

Tags: python

Given a string in the format :

```
A = "photo.jpeg, Warsaw,2013-09-05 14:08:15\njohn.png, London, 2015-06-20 15:13:22\nmyFriends.png, Warsaw, 2013-09-05 14:07:13"
```

I can split it using the splitlines function. But I need to sort the entries like - Within each city sort the entries based on time and return the city.number.extension 
So in the above there are three entries so the following will be returned

```
Warsaw2.jpeg
London1.png
Warsaw1.jpeg
```

Since when sorting the entries with city = Warsaw based on the time the first entry will come in the 2nd position. So basically for each entry convert it to city.number.extension
where the number will be the position it will appear when the entries for the same city name are sorted based on the time.

```
def comp2(a, b):
    city1 = a.split(",")[1].strip()
    city2 = b.split(",")[1].strip()
    if city1 < city2:
        return 1
    elif city1 > city2:
        return -1
    return 0


def solution(S):
    entries = S.splitlines()
    entries.sort(key=comp2)
```

I have currently implemented this code but it's giving an error : 
 comp2() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'

Comment: Please provide us with code of what you made so far.

Comment: Also, please, make sure your string sample is correct - there is inconsistent use of space after comma. Is this really the case in actual data?

Comment: @buran yes there is a space after a comma so I am using the strip() function in the code above to remove it

Comment: @Thyrus I can sort the entries by the city name which will automatically group the cities. But then I have to sort the groupby by the date I am not sure if there is an easy way to do it. Also I loose the row identification. Probably I will need to insert a special identifier for each entry

Comment: @daniel did you try to use Regular Expresions, maybe that will help?

Answer (score 0):

The value of the `key` parameter of the `sort` function has to be a function which takes only 1 parameter, check [the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort). So you need to convert your compare function by using [the `cmp_to_key` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cmp_to_key). Applied to your example you need to change the line `entries.sort(key=comp2)` to `entries.sort(key=functools.cmp_to_key(comp2))`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a much prettier way of performing the task put for getting it working for you I developed the following solution. I have included comments to show what I am doing throughout the process. If you need any further input let me know.

```
initial_list = "photo.jpeg, Warsaw,2013-09-05 14:08:15\njohn.png, London, 2015-06-20 15:13:22\nmyFriends.png, Warsaw, 2013-09-05 14:07:13"
initial_list = initial_list.split('\n') # Split on new line
initial_list = [i.split(',') for i in initial_list] # Split on comma
initial_list = [[i.strip() for i in j] for j in initial_list] # Strip whitespaces

# Get extension from first element of list
extension = [item[0].split(".")[1] for item in initial_list]
cities = [item[1] for item in initial_list]

# Count occurrences of each city
cities_count = {}
for city in cities:
    if city in cities_count:
        cities_count[city] += 1
    else:
        cities_count[city] = 1

# Generate list of photo name with city + count + extension
photo_list = []
for item in initial_list:
    photo_list.append(item[1] + str(cities_count[item[1]]) + "." + extension[initial_list.index(item)])

for index, item in enumerate(initial_list):
    initial_list[index][0] = photo_list[index]

# Sort list based on time 
initial_list = sorted(initial_list, key=lambda x: x[2])
# Reverse by doing sorted(initial_list, key=lambda x: x[2], reverse=True)
```

Please note I changed your variable name in this example to better suit what I am working with.